# Numpy: get the index of the top value sorted that are superior to 0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array and I wan to have the index of the top value sorted that are superior to 0 for instance:

```
[-0.4, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7]
```

And I want to have:

```
[6, 1, 4, 5]
```

I can do it using a function I implemented but I guess for this kind of task there is something already implemented in Numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do:

```
L = [-0.4, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7]

[L.index(i) for i in sorted(filter(lambda x: x>0, L), reverse=True)]

Out[72]: [6, 1, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement with `np.where`

```
a = np.array([-0.4, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7])
np.where(a > 0)[0].tolist()
```

**Result**

```
[1, 4, 5, 6]
```

The result of `np.where(a > 0)` is in the form of tuple of numpy array. So can converted into list with using `tolist()`

Comment: Yeah but what about the order of the index?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized approach -

```
idx = np.where(A>0)[0]
out = idx[A[idx].argsort()[::-1]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [37]: A = np.array([-0.4, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7])

In [38]: idx = np.where(A>0)[0]

In [39]: idx[A[idx].argsort()[::-1]]
Out[39]: array([6, 1, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.where()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

`d > 0.0` generates a boolean mask and `where` fetches all the values where the mask is true.

```
>>> d=np.array([-0.4, 0.6, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0.7])
>>> r=np.where( d > 0)
>>> s=sorted(r[0].tolist(), key=lambda x:d[x], reverse=True)
>>> s
[6L, 1L, 4L, 5L]
```

**EDIT**

Here's what I mean by mask.

```
>>> mask = d > 0
>>> mask
array([False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Yeah but what about the order of the index?